# Is there a way to access Google Docs' new Action Items via the Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

The Drive API allows access to Comments and Changes on documents but I don't see the new [action items](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/five-new-ways-reach-your-goals-faster-g-suite/) feature in the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/).

Is there a way to perform any of the standard CRUD operations on them: get a list of them, get their properties, add new ones, modify them, etc.?

I'm actually interested in doing this through Google Apps Script but I understand that even Comments are only available in the Drive API, so I suspect if there's a way to do it it would be through the Drive API first.

Comment: I also checked the docs myself. It seems this is not supported as of the moment as the API for this functionality is not exposed and has something to do with intuitive AI.

Comment: For future reference, I just answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58234939/3315914