# Term for followup, looking for actionitems

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I wanted to write a quick script to remind myself of follow-up action items put on the various google documents, out of google drive to benefit from the API list(). However, it seems the `followup:actionitems` search query is not working with the API, as the search term is not known. It returns a 400 error.

For example, doing this:

```
results = service.files().list(q="followup:actionitems",
                                   pageSize=50,
                                   pageToken=page_token,
                                   fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./reminder.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "./reminder.py", line 38, in main
    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
  File "/home/x/.virtualenvs/gdocs-followup-reminder-7WeAWiqi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/x/.virtualenvs/gdocs-followup-reminder-7WeAWiqi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 856, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=followup%3Aactionitems&pageSize=50&fields=nextPageToken%2C+files%28id%2C+name%29&alt=json returned "Invalid Value">
```

Is there something I am missing? Not the right usage? Or is it planned to have that in the future?

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo. I added a snippet. The explanation as to why it does not work was part of the initial post: "the search term is not known".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish that setting the `q` parameter to

```
fullText contains 'followup:actionitems' and trashed = false
```

returns the same files as Google Drive UI does

Comment: Right on. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

The q parameter is very nice it lets you search for files and directories in Google drive.  However it does not let you search on all of the properties of a file.   As far as i know followup action items is not one of them.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#operators)

The Google docs api to my knowledge does not have a q parameter for searching the contents of a file.

Really i think that `followup:actionitems` is out of scope for the Google drive api its just a file storage api it doesn't keep track of any settings you setup in the Google drive web application. as you can see from the [file.resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) object that isnt even a properly on a file in google drive api